# How can we install multiple apache servers at different ports in aws ec2 linux instance

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-ec2, instance

I want to install multiple apache servers on ec2 linux servers operating at different ports and having different file structures in one ec2 linux machine.
Please guide me on how can i install multiple apache servers in one machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run a single apache server using the `VirtualHost` directive.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.org
  DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain-80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName www.example2.org
  DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain-8080
</VirtualHost>
```

Will listen to both port `80` and `8080` running the same apache server. Running two apache instances on the same server is possible but it's kinda messy. Keep in mind that any port > 1024 is protected by Linux, you will only be able to bind ports 443 and 80 with Apache, otherwise it has to be ports 1025 and above.

More information here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: k.k.gt the answer sir.thanks.one more small query i had,If we want to make a server machine in separate shared hosting domains kind of servers,like the hosting companies do.How can we achieve that?

Comment: @stack I'm not sure if I understand the question. You mean behind a load balancer?

Comment: not a load balancer.Like the hosting  companies have used one dedicated server and inside that they make a lot of small shared servers which they say as shared hosting domains.How they divide that and give it to different customers.